# How to use query function with bool in python pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to do something like

```
df.query("'column' == 'a'").count()
```

but with

```
df.query("'column' == False").count()
```

What is the right way of using `query` with a bool column?

Comment: Simply `df.query("column == False")`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's simply `'column == False'`.

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([[False, 1], [True, 2], [False, 3]], columns=['column', 'another_column'])                       
>>> df                                                                                                                 
   column  another_column
0   False               1
1    True               2
2   False               3
>>> df.query('column == False')                                                                                        
   column  another_column
0   False               1
2   False               3
>>> df.query('column == False').count()                                                                                
column            2
another_column    2
dtype: int64
```

Personally, I prefer boolean indexing (if applicable to your situation).

```
>>> df[~df['column']]                                                                                                  
   column  another_column
0   False               1
2   False               3
>>> df[~df['column']].count()                                                                                          
column            2
another_column    2
dtype: int64
```

Comment: While not the specific question, to get the count of false values include a column name, something like `df.query('column == False').column.count()` .

Answer (score 3):

Even simpler using query:

```
df.query("~column").count()
```

**Actually, below are the non-query ways to do it, they are actually not as pretty and can be slower (as query is sometimes very optimized)**

Though you really should be using:

```
df[~df["column"]].count()
```

or if you prefer (more readable, but not always possible):

```
df[~df.column].count()
```

Answer (score -1):

Pandas uses **pandas.eval()** to evaluate code you pass to the **pandas.query()**.
**pandas.eval()** makes [this](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.eval.html#pandas.eval):

> Evaluate a Python expression as a string using various backends.

In Python you need to use **is** operator to compare False to anything, simply because if you compare something to False you will always get False as result(That's how Python works, I don't really know why).
**pandas.query()** seems to not support **is** statement, but we have workarounds:

- We can check if **column != column**. If that returns True, that means that we are comparing some value to False.
  Use **df.query("column != False")**
- We can use pandas functions if we pass pandas library in the *local_dict* keyword parameter. Like:

  ```
  import pandas as pd
  local_vars = {'pd': pd}
  df.query(expr="@pd.isna(column)",local_dict=local_vars)
  ```

Also I am not sure what are you trying to do with **count()** as **count()** counts `non-NA cells for each column or row`.

- If you are trying to simply count the rows, than use **shape**.
- If you are trying to count how many NA-cells are in each column, using only rows where *column* equals to False, than its OK and should work

P.S don't use quotes around column name in **df.query()**.

Comment: Not true: "In Python you need to use is operator to compare False to anything, simply because if you compare something to False you will always get False as result(That's how Python works, I don't really know why)."